Hierarchical/navigational database engine available on RSX-11M
Around 1988-1990 I worked for a company that was using an old RSX-11M system to host an ERP application. The application used a third-party database product of which I am trying to recall the name. This was a hierarchical/navigational type of database (not relational). The system had been in-use for some years prior to 1988, was becoming obsolete at that point, although the database product was still supported by the vendor - they were still offering training on their product.
What database product(s) would have been available which would meet these criteria:

Existed for some years prior to 1988, vendor (third-party, not DEC) still in business and supporting the product at that time (1989-ish)
Hierarchical/navigational (non-relational) database engine i.e. records used links/pointers to define data relationships
Available on RSX-11M
Vendor provided training out of their office in Eastern Virginia (Reston?)


Was it MUMPS? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS

DEC had the CODASYL dbms, and I’m pretty sure it also ran on RSX-11.

@mannaggia No. I've seen that name before, many years ago, but that was not the product I was working with.

@RonJohn It was a third-party product, not DEC.

DEC had Datatrieve on verious operating systems.  RSX-11M may have been one of them.  Datatrieve was not a datamanagement system.  It used underlying facilities like RMS to actually access the Data.  It had a good data manipulation language somewhat like SQL and a good report generator built in.  Datatrieve was closer to relational than to hierachical in its constructs.  There was a CODASYL DBMS on the PDP-10 and the VAX, and I'm guessing there was one on RSX.

Is "ERP" "enterprise resource planning"?

Could it have been Cullinet's IDMS-11? Which I believe was also resold by DEC as DBMS-11, but originally developed by B.F. Goodrich (who then spun it out as Cullinane/Cullinet) not DEC. Here is a 1977 article discussing its development: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/954639.954646 – and apparently Cullinane/Cullinet had an office in Reston at one point
